# MongoDb $setIntersection with Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

i want to build the following mongodb-json-query with the java driver from mongodb:

```
db.item.aggregate([
{'$project': { attr: { 
              $setIntersection:["$structureAttributeValueIdList", [ObjectId("54bfba08ef6643acaa5be2c9")]]
    }, _id : 0, document: "$$ROOT"            
}},
{ "$unwind": "$attr" },
{ "$match": { "document.stateDeleted" : 0 } }]);
```

What I have so far ist this:

```
 DBObject intersection =
   new BasicDBObject( "$setIntersection", ???? );

  DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject( "attributes", intersection );
  fields.put( " document", "$$ROOT" );
  fields.put( "_id", 0 );
  DBObject project = new BasicDBObject( "$project", fields );

  DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject( "$unwind", "attributes" );

  DBObject match =
      new BasicDBObject( "$match", new BasicDBObject( "document.stateDeleted", 0 ) );

  List< DBObject > pipeline = Arrays.asList( project, unwind, match );

  AggregationOutput output = operations.getCollection( "item" ).aggregate( pipeline );
```

But i dont know how to build the setIntersection-Part!
Any help?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by myself ... very easy when you know how

```
BasicDBList intersectionList = new BasicDBList();
intersectionList.add( "$structureAttributeValueIdList" );
intersectionList.add( objectIdDBList );
DBObject intersection = new BasicDBObject( "$setIntersection", intersectionList );
```